# Gnome-flashback and 4k display

Tags: 20.04, themes, display-resolution, css, gnome-flashback

I am using gnome-flashback with 4k display and 200% scaling. It works fine but some of the icons are too small (e. g. in window button list and one of the notification panels), and also there is too narrow line interval in the menus. I tried to edit some theme css but got no effect.

Is there a way to enlarge mentioned elements? Or maybe there is already a theme (like "ambiance" if possible) that is adapted to 4k resolution? Or is there another shell which looks like good old gnome 2 but works with 4k?

Thanks in advance.